# Titanium Studio Mac OS 10.9 Error Running IOS Simulator

Tags: android, xcode, macos, titanium, ios-simulator

When I attempt to Run the default Kitchen Sink sample app import on Titanium Studio, i get an error when i attempt to Run the app - as the picture below (TypeError: Invalid Version: android-sdk-macos.0.0).

I had downloaded the latest of everything (SDK, app, etc) and i have no luck with it.

System Running:

-Xcode 6.1

-Titanium Studio 3.4.0 GA (latest)

-Android SDK MacOS r23.0.2

-Mac OS 10.9

I can't get this error cleared.

I also get a "No Android SDK found in the selected path" error under:

Preferences->Studio->Platforms->Android

Even though the path is correct, and I extracted the sdk labled "android-sdk-macos" into "/Users/'name'/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/android-sdk-macos" which is also where the Preferences for Android is also pointing to.

My SDK Manager is shown below to show the packages i have installed under the same path and the manager reads/writes the files fine. (so i scratched out premissions issues-i also included Everyone to read/write to the Xcode.app packages folder)

Any idea or help is greatly appreciated! I am going to keep digging forums and docs, so far no avail.

[image: Problem Occured]

[image: Android SDK Manager on Mac OS]

Answer (score 0):

change xcode simulator path in titanium....then run

Comment: please elaborate your answer to make a clear and more understandable answer for OP

Comment: Nikunj, please clearify where I can change the xcode simulator path on Titanium? I am under the impression (and seemingly on the prefrences of Titanium) that the Xcode path is automatically found and set. Perhaps I am missing something by your answer? Your time and efforts are greatly appreciated.

Comment: give your skype id i will change your path.